# SyntaxError using quotation marks in terminal

Tags: python, syntax, python-2.x

Every time I write some code with`"` and run it in terminal - it shows me error - how can I fix that?

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Radani:Books radani$ python 2.py
  File "2.py", line 16
    Print "what is 5 - 7?", 5-7 
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Do you actually have `Print` in your file? It's spelled `print`.

Answer (score 2):

The `print` command in python is all lower case.

```
>>> print "what is 5 - 7?"
what is 5 - 7?
```